# show and hide div from bottom to top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hide, show

I have this example with a div which show / hide from the top, but I need it from the bottom to the top, I was trying to change some code, but I couldn't, and I didn't find any example.

```
<style type="text/css">

#top-panel{
    background:#cc22ff;
    border-bottom:3px solid #a6c34e;
    padding:14px 20px;
    text-align:right;   
}
#sub-panel{
    text-align:center;
}
#sub-panel a{
    width:150px;
    float:right;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    text-decoration:none;
    margin-right:30px;
    font-weight:bold;
    background:url(img/sub-left.png) bottom left no-repeat #a6c34e;
}
#sub-panel a span{
    padding:6px;
    background:url(img/sub-right.png) right bottom no-repeat;
    display:block;

}
strong{color:#000000;}
.face{border:solid 2px #a6c34e; margin-left:10px; float:right;}
:focus{outline:0}
</style> 


<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Lets make the top panel toggle based on the click of the show/hide link  
    $("#sub-panel").click(function(){
        // Toggle the bar up 
        $("#top-panel").slideToggle();  
        // Settings
        var el = $("#shText");  
        // Lets us know whats inside the element
        var state = $("#shText").html();
        // Change the state  
        state = (state == 'Hide' ? '<span id="shText">Mostrar</span>' : '<span id="shText">Ocultar</span>');                    
        // Finally change whats insdide the element ID
        el.replaceWith(state); 
    }); // end sub panel click function
}); // end on DOM
</script> 


<div id="top-panel">
<strong>titulo</strong><br />
contenido
</div>
<div id="sub-panel"><a href="#" id="toggle"><span id="shText">Ocultar</span></a></div>
```

Comment: You didn't try anything, right? The code as is I'm pretty sure it can be found googling

Comment: yes, I was searching and searching, and finally I found a solution here http://return-true.com/2010/04/jquery-pop-up-footer-version-2/

maybe can be usefull for someone else.

Answer (score 4):

Use `$("#top-panel").slideUp();`  instead of `slideToggle()`

Comment: Why should that be used instead?

Comment: Adding a comment will not hurt and will improve the answer so others understand you answer

Comment: @afuzzyllama, well (?) then the box will hide _from the bottom to the top_, as asked for.

Comment: While reviewing your answer, I cannot tell the difference between the two functions.  Explaining more thoroughly will help others with the same problem in the future :)

Comment: Yes, but i thought it was pretty obvious in this particular case. If you have copied the html/script into a file and seen it for yourself in a browser i think you would notice a difference that pretty much fullfills the need for _from the bottom to the top_ But who knows, we will never get clarified if "Maru" really is satisfied, the question is appearently forgotten or not important anymore - longer explanation or not...But point taken

Comment: Sorry guys! I was trying to find another alternative, here is an example, maybe can be usefull for someone else.
Thanks to all of you! :)
 http://return-true.com/2010/04/jquer...ter-version-2/